# Как добавить транзитную точку используя control.RoutePanel

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача: пользователю нужно выбрать точку A и B, чтобы построился маршрут. Но при этом, чтобы добавлялась транзитная точка, чтобы можно было гибко изменять середину маршрута.
Сейчас у меня код, аналогичный примеру из [документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator), который использует control.RoutePanel.

А хотелось бы, чтобы после построения маршрута, появлялась транзитная точка, как в [этом примере из документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options).

Я пробовал добавлять код, подобный этому, но он не срабатывает:

```
this.routePanelControl.routePanel
        .getRouteAsync()
        .then(function(multiRoute) {
          multiRoute.events.add("update", function() {
multiRoute.options.set({viaIndexes: [2]})
}
});
```

Такое ощущение, что я не могу добавить эту точку после того, как маршрут уже построен без неё.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент control.RoutePanel не поддерживает добавление промежуточных точек.
Нужно писать свой собственный контрол, который бы это поддерживал.

Пример, с чего начать при написании собственного контрола, можно найти тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А нет возможности реализовать такой функционал без control.RoutePanel, а только средствами multiRouter? 
Чтобы было как в [этом примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_edit), но даже первую точку указывал бы пользователь? Ну и транзитная точка добавлялась. Я, собственно, пришел к control.RoutePanel, потому что у меня не получилось это сделать без него.

Comment: конечно можно это сделать без control.RoutePanel, а только средствами multiRouter https://jsfiddle.net/06edobkz/

Comment: Большое спасибо, что показали пример!
У меня возникло два вопроса теперь:
1) Не получилось ограничить количество waypoint'ов до двух (только точки A и B). Пробовал для этого код из примера в документации, но обычного Route.
2) Если построить маршрут из двух точек, то не срабатывает метод multiRoute.getActiveRoute(). Почему то он срабатывает только когда появляется третий WayPoint. multiRoute.getRoutes().getLength() показывает 0, когда две точки.
[Форкнул ваш пример](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyKot/7wtk2g1e/5/)
Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Не самое удачное событие вы выбрали, событие update больше подходит в таком случае https://jsfiddle.net/wbvtdp0L/

Comment: Спасибо! А по второму вопросу, почему getRoutes().getLength() возвращает в моем примере 0?

Comment: С этим разобрался, нужно было просто в событие "requestsuccess" это добавить